# what is content (reference) content: TemplateRef<any> in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap

Hello I'm staring to work with Angular, when I was adding a modal with bootstrap into my html I found I need to send the parameter content which I never declarete

```
<tbody *ngIf="!loading">
        <tr
          (click)="openModal(content,note)"
          *ngFor="let note of notesAndCommentsContainer"
        >
          <td>{{ note.author }}</td>
          <td>{{ note.preview }}</td>
          <td>{{ note.property }}</td>
          <td>{{ note.date }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

and get in the typescript the next

```
openModal(content:object,note:object) {
    this.modalTitle = note['author'];
    this.modalDate = note['date'];
    this.modalBody = note['comment'];
    this.commentProperty = note['property'];
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'})    
  }
```

this is something curious and I want to know how to generate this object from typescript because it is necessary to launch a bootstrap modal in angular I'm using Angular 12.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content can be provided as a `TemplateRef` or a component type.

So you can create a new component and pass it to the function:

```
this.modalService.open(YourModalComponent, yourOptions)
```

not passing the content from your template (so only `openModal(note)`) or you can declare a template inside your component:

```
<ng-template #yourModalTemplate let-modal>
...
</ng-template>
```

Passing it thanks to the reference `#yourModalTemplate` (you can give it the name you like)

```
<tr (click)="openModal(yourModalTemplate,note)" ...>
```

If you pass a component type as content, then instances of those components can be injected with an instance of the `NgbActiveModal` class. You can then use `NgbActiveModal` methods to close / dismiss modals from "inside" of your component.

Some useful links:

- Modal API: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbModalOptions
- Tutorial: https://www.remotestack.io/angular-bootstrap-modal-popup-tutorial-example/